# Query Form Logic: "Like" vs. "Equals"

Tags: sql, database

Our application provides multiple query interfaces that are basically just text inputs.  Is there a best practice on whether the backend logic should be pad the query parameter with wildcards then perform a like or should it just do an equals.  Of course another option would be to allow user's to use wildcards and then check and use a "like" if appropriate.

I understand the performance implication of using a wildcard like this and that this could be viewed as a subject question, I just want to know if there is a standard practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something I would leave up to the user, allowing then to actually make a choice. All the UIs I've seen for allowing user-specified conditions have:

- the column to check.
- a drop-down box containing the relationship, such as `equal to`, `not equal to`, `less than`, `greater than`, `starts with`.
- the value you want to compare to.

Then, for the `starts with` option, you just tack on `%` and use `like`.

You'll note (for performance reasons which you seem to already understand) I used `starts with` rather than `like` to limit the possibility of dragging down the database performance.

I'm not a big fan of unrestricted `like` statements although you could also provide `ends with` for those DBMS' capable of storing reversed indexes.

Comment: You'd use aligator brackets for string comparison?

Comment: Depends on the users. To be honest, I'd probably have `not equal to` (and textual representations for all the others as well) since they may understand neither `<>` nor `!=`.